Workflow validation failed for the workflow 'shiptest'. {"error":{"code":"WorkflowTriggerTypeUnsupported",
Workflow validation failed for the workflow 'shiptest'. {"error":
{"code":"WorkflowTriggerTypeUnsupported","message":"The stateless workflow trigger 
'When_a_new_email_arrives_(V3)' has type 'ApiConnectionNotification', which is not 
supported in stateless workflows. Switching to stateful workflow or replacing trigger
 'When_a_new_email_arrives_(V3)' may resolve this error."}}


This is the workflow in my Azure Standard Logic App.
Environment:

I'm using Microsoft 365 Outlook, Azure Standard Logic App which is VNet Enabled with public access disabled.
I'm using Stateless workflow because every 10 minutes I'll get the attachments mail from the users.

Workflow:

When a new email with attachments comes to me, it should be uploaded the blob container.

Unable to identify which outlook connector I have to use.
Could anyone help me on this.

Have you tried the same workflow in stateful standard logic app?

Trying it but meanwhile if you get any solution in the stateless, could you please provide it.

@IkhtesamAfrin, Got the same message in stateful workflow Workflow validation failed for the workflow 'ridershipteststateful'. {"error":{"code":"WorkflowRunActionTypeUnsupported","message":"The workflow run action 'When_a_new_email_arrives_(V3)' has type 'ApiConnectionNotification' that is not supported."}}


Workflow validation failed for the workflow 'shiptest'. {"error":
{"code":"WorkflowTriggerTypeUnsupported","message":"The stateless workflow trigger  'When_a_new_email_arrives_(V3)' has type  'ApiConnectionNotification', which is not  supported in stateless workflows. Switching to stateful workflow or replacing trigger  'When_a_new_email_arrives_(V3)' may resolve this error."}}

The error message itself says that Microsoft 365 Outlook  and some other managed connectors are not supported in stateless workflow instead consider using the same connector in stateful workflow.
You can check Changed, limited, unavailable, or unsupported capabilities to know more about the limitations in stateless standard logic app.
I have used When a new email arrives (V3) trigger in stateful workflow and also able to save it successfully.

Stateless workflow uses built-in connectors as per MS Docs.

For a Standard logic app stateful workflow, all managed connectors appear in the designer under the Azure label, which describes how these connectors are hosted on the Azure platform. A Standard stateless workflow can use only the built-in connectors designed to run natively in single-tenant Azure Logic Apps.

